# Automatically update Google form responses when they are submitted

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have users submitting requests via Google form. One of these requests is a "Priority" where they can choose Low-Medium-High and each answer also has a short few word descript of what that means.

I track all of these requests in Asana on a Board thanks to a Zapier integration.

I would LOVE to be able to append the "Priority" as a tag in Asana automatically. Unfortunately Zapier -> Asana tagging works on the Asana Tag ID not the plain text name of the tag. I have the IDs associated to each "Priority" response but it wouldn't make sense to an end user to select the priority of "123412341234" for "High".

Is there a way for when a Form response is submitted to instantly update the response for a specific column based on a match table? Essentially, if the person responds "High" instead record "123412341234".

I am not a super strong programmer as I am on the Program & Product management side trying to build this as a side project for my small analyst team but I am happy to try to understand any and all code you send my way.

First submission so please let me know if you need more information and thank you for your time!

Comment: Welcome Thane. Regarding participating on this site, please take the [tour] and checkout [ask]. Regarding [google-apps-script] you should bear in mind that you could add a on form submit trigger to the form or to the spreadsheet, but the event object is not the same. Perhaps you should to add the on form submit trigger to the spreadsheet because the integration with Asana through Zappier.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of trying this without a script? One possible approach is to query the form data in a different tab. with something like.

```
=QUERY('Form responses 1'!A1:B)
```

Then in an adjacent column you could use an array formula with a conditional that looks at the response and makes it into a number.

=ARRAYFORMULA(if(B:B="Medium","3030404",""))

I made an example [here.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1islmMVbE4jz78At6HEh0HgQgE7hxId9MrJAldLK1PK8/edit?usp=sharing)